# Sharp lines on texture paint?

Tags: texture-painting

Is there something special getting sharper strokes/lines on texture paint mode? I'm trying to get a texture that seems like it was drawn with a sharp pencil (like sketching) but I get very low resolution lines. I'm new with blender.

Answer (score 1):

In the *N panel > Tool > Brush Settings > Falloff*, there are different brush shapes, you can also tweak the curve:

[image]

If I choose the square one here is what I get:

[image]

Also in the same panel, under *Texture Mask*, you can load a texture to have something that will look more accidental etc...

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it :)

Comment: I'm not sure it answered as your question is a bit vague, maybe add zome details  ;)